# error 401 : unauthorized, received even after using API key while using www.openweathermap.org

Tags: javascript, api, openweathermap

Hi I am buliding my first web app using javascript and fetching data using API from www.openweathermap.org/ 
I have used the API key as mentioned in the documentation still it is giving an error of unauthorization. Can there be any other reason for this error while calling a function or so . Thank you in advance.

```
    var APPID = "my_secret_key";
    var temp;
    var loc;
    var icon;
    var wind;
    var humidity;
    var direction;
    function updateByZip(zip){
      var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?" + 
                "zip = " + zip +
                "&APPID =" + APPID ;
    sendRequest(url);
     }

    function sendRequest(url){
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
         var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText) ;
         var weather = {}; 
         weather.wind = data.wind.speed; 
         weather.direction = data.wind.deg;
         weather.loc = data.name;
         weather.temp = data.main.temp;
         weather.icon = data.weather[0].id;
         weather.humidity=data.main.humidity;
         update(weather);
        }
       };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
```

Comment: Putting that URL in a browser works just fine.  What does `sendRequest` do exactly?  perhaps it is mistakenly sending it POST?

Comment: send request sends a request  for receiving  weather data . I can add the code if you want. Also I have used "GET"

Comment: I believe you're having a CROS issue. The last time I tried to fetch data from OpenWeatherMap it was not working. (I found this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rover/HWAFG/) and the console shows a [CORS error](http://i.imgur.com/QXKayKz.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the spaces near the equal signs in your URL.  It's likely urlencoding the space and sending your parameter as `APPID%20` which is not being recognized as valid.

```
  var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?" + 
            "zip=" + zip +
            "&APPID=" + APPID;
```

Comment: yeah this worked fine !! Thank you !! although there are still some error in my function, will check it.

Answer (score 0):

for future users, as i was having 401 error but solved it differently.

**Error:**
*Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info*

**API calls responds with 401 error:**
You can get the error 401 in the following cases:

- You did not specify your [API key](https://openweathermap.org/appid) in API request.
- Your API key is not activated yet. Within the next couple of hours, it will be activated and ready to use.
- You are using wrong API key in API request. Please, check your right API key in [personal account](https://home.openweathermap.org/api_keys).
- You have **free** subscription and try to get access to our paid services (for example, [16 days/daily forecast API](https://openweathermap.org/forecast16), [any historical weather data](https://openweathermap.org/price#history), [Weather maps 2.0](https://openweathermap.org/api/weather-map-2), etc). Please, check your tariff in your [personal account]([[price and condition]](https://openweathermap.org/price)).

here are some steps to find problem.

## 1) Check if API key is activated

some API services provide key information in dashboard whether its activated, expired etc. openWeatherMap don't.
to verify whether your key is working 'MAKE API CALL FROM BROWSER'
`api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=peshawar&appid=API_key`

*replace API_key with your own key, if you get data successfully then your key is activated otherwise wait for few hours to get key activated.*

## 2) Check .env for typos & syntax

.env is file which is used to hide credentials such as API_KEY in server side code.
make sure your .env file variables are using correct syntax which is
NAME=VALUE

```
API_KEY=djgkv43439d90bkckcs
```

*no semicolon, quotes etc*

## 3) Check request URL

check request url where API call will be made , make sure

- It doesn't have spaces, braces etc
- correct according to URL encoding
- correct according to API documentation

## 4) Debug using dotenv:

to know if you dotenv package is parsing API key correctly use the following code

```
const result = dotenv.config()

if (result.error) {
  throw result.error
} 
console.log(result.parsed)
```

*this code checks if .env file variables are being parsed, it will print API_KEY value if its been parsed otherwise will print error which occur while parsing.*

*Hopefully it helps :)*

## Others suggestion

### 5) Check location of .env file

look for location of .env file in your directory, moving it to root directory might help (suggested in comments)

Comment: This is as excellent answer. I'll also add that I came across this problem yesterday and it was because my .env file was not in the root folder of my project. So if the issue persists and you've done all of the above, check the location of your .env file.

Answer (score 0):

For those who followed the previous answers and are still facing the 401 issue: it seems it is now required to access the the API via HTTPS --- at least that's the case for me. Some older guides and tutorials might continue to use `http://` in their code, so you'll have to change it to `https://`.

As far as I know, there is no mention of this in OpenWeather's official docs, and they don't include the protocol in their examples too.